# Camera Activity returns null URI

Tags: android, file, android-activity, camera, storage

**I was testing my app on a Samsung Note,
here was how i used to call the camera**

```
Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(captureIntent, CAMERA_CAPTURE);
```

then in the activity result:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        if(requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE)
        {
            picUri = data.getData();
            //continue my code
        }
    }
}
```

**but then i recently changed testing to a Galaxy Nexus and i noticed that data.getData() now returns null rather than the temp image uri.
i read a couple of recommendations and all mentioned passing a file to the camera activity to be the location of the new iamge.
now i changed the code to:**

```
....
File photoFile = createImageFile();
//photoFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),  "Pic.jpg");
captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
startActivityForResult(captureIntent, CAMERA_CAPTURE);
....
```

using the method

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException
{
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    //File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "alboom");
    //File storageDir = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "alboom");
    //File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    //File storageDir = getFilesDir();  //not working
    //File storageDir = getDir("mydir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);  //not working
    //File storageDir = getCacheDir();  //not working

    if (!storageDir.mkdirs())   //required if creating a new dir
        Log.e(TAG, "Directory not created");

    //File image = File.createTempFile( imageFileName,  ".jpg", storageDir );
    File image = new File(storageDir, imageFileName);   
    //File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg");  //not working


    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

and the result handling

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        if(requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE)
        {
            picUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);
            //continue my code
        }
    }
}
```

now my code is working well but only when im writing to external storage.. internal storage always doesnt return from the camera activity.

**My Questions are:**

1. why cant i write to internal storage?
2. How to write an "unhidden" image file to external storage?
3. why did the old code stop working?

Comment: "why cant i write to internal storage?" -- because the camera app does not have access to your app's internal storage.

Comment: yep. Samsung camera app returns null as of android 4.3 when you pass an `EXTRA_OUTPUT`. but then you don't really need the `data.getData()` Uri, as you already know what the Uri is

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for explaining.. furthermore i noticed that writing to external storage writes a hidden file, is there a way to write a file that is NOT hidden

Comment: "i noticed that writing to external storage writes a hidden file" -- I have no idea what you mean by this, sorry.

Comment: @CommonsWare the new files are hidden and inaccessible on my pc.... then i noticed that after a while they do appear and also in the gallery

Comment: You will need to scan the file using `MediaScannerConnection` and `scanFile()` to get it to show up in gallery apps faster. That will also help the PC, though due to the nature of the MTP connection between the PC and the device, you may need to manually refresh the directory listing or unplug and plug back in the device to get your file to show up.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks so much for your help, but back to q1, can i give access to the camera for the internal memory

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, despite of write something like this:

```
File source = null;
source = new File(imageUri.getPath());
```

or:

```
Uri url= Uri.parse(stringPath);
```

...it's possible that you obtain a null value for your uri. It seems related to a bug with the last android version (4.4.4). What to do, then? A trick is to force a new image saving in order to refresh the path:

```
 Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), imageBitmap);
```

(...)

```
public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
  ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
  String path = Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
  return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

Try it! You can also [take a look at this](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/741165/why-capture-image-path-return-null-in-android).